# Numpy vectorized less than/greater than comparisons

Tags: python, numpy

I have some code to match up angles to the quadrants of the circle they fall into. It currently gives me the results I want, but I'm trying to lose the for loop to make full use of numpy's speed.

```
import numpy as np

angle = np.array([350, 10, 80, 100, 170, 190, 260, 280])
# Center of each quadrant
spawn_angles = np.array([0, 90, 180, 270])

segment_degrees = np.diff(spawn_angles)[0]
lower_bounds = spawn_angles - (segment_degrees / 2)
upper_bounds = spawn_angles + (segment_degrees / 2)
max_upper = upper_bounds.max()
# Wrap angles larger than the upper bound of the last segment
# back to a negative angle
angle[angle > max_upper] -= 360
quadrant = np.zeros_like(angle, dtype=np.float64)
# Want to make sure that quadrants that don't get calculated
# properly get assigned an invalid number, i.e. -1
quadrant.fill(-1)
for segment_num in range(len(spawn_angles)):
    in_segment = ((angle > lower_bounds[segment_num]) & 
                  (angle < upper_bounds[segment_num]))
    quadrant[in_segment] = segment_num

# Expected/current output
quadrant
Out[16]: array([ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.])
```

Basically the part that I can't figure out how to do within numpy is the `>`/`<` comparison.
If the angle is between `lower_bounds[0]` and `upper_bounds[0]`, the corresponding entry
of `quadrant` gets assigned 0, and similarly for quadrants 1, 2, 3. Is there any way
to compare the angle array to all the entries of `lower_bound` and/or `upper_bound` simultaneously?

(If this code seems overcomplicated, some of that is because the `spawn_angles`/quadrant centers
are not always `[0, 90, 180, 270]`, they can also be e.g. `[45, 135, 225, 315]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lift everything up one dimension. You want a 2D array, with each angle as a row and each segment_num as a column. (Or maybe you want the transpose, but if so, you should be able to figure that out from here.)

If you just do `a > b` where `a` and `b` are both 1D arrays, you're asking for a 1-to-1 elementwise comparison.

But if `a` is a 2D array, you're asking for a cartesian product comparison.

In other words:

```
>>> array.reshape((8,1)) > lower_bounds
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

And you should be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: Great, got it, thanks for the nudge in the right direction. I'll post my reworked code as a solution shortly, let me know if you notice any obvious errors.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to abarnert for the key insight here. My reworked vectorized code:

```
import numpy as np

angle = np.array([350, 10, 80, 100, 170, 190, 260, 280])
# Center of each quadrant
spawn_angles = np.array([0, 90, 180, 270])

segment_degrees = np.diff(spawn_angles)[0]
lower_bounds = spawn_angles - (segment_degrees / 2)
upper_bounds = spawn_angles + (segment_degrees / 2)
max_upper = upper_bounds.max()
# Wrap angles larger than the upper bound of the last segment
# back to a negative angle
angle[angle > max_upper] -= 360
angle_2d = angle.reshape((len(angle), 1))
cmp_array = ((angle_2d > lower_bounds) & 
             (angle_2d < upper_bounds))
quadrant = np.argwhere(cmp_array)[:, 1]
quadrant
Out[29]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Just for future reference, you can rewrite
angle_2d = angle.reshape((len(angle), 1))
to 
angle_2d = angle.reshape((-1, 1))